# Error in my string passing into the function which is a pointer in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

**Instruction:** Alright, I am working on a code where I am doing number conversions. I am prompting the user to give me a base and an input of bits with a mathematic symbol such as '+', '-', '*' etc, and I do the calculation, if you have a strategy for that, then feel free to give me an idea.

**Problem:** Regardless, I am working on some strategy on how to do it, but I am having trouble with my character, strings, char pointers. I don't know how to resolve it. I hardly understand what pointers are, besides a location in memory. I need help resolving this problem.

**baseToDec Function:** Anyways, I have a method/function called baseToDec, where I perform a conversion from bits to a decimal and return an int. Inside those parameters, I have a char* which takes in the value. such as '1001' which is the value 9.

**Ways:** However, when I put in the string "first" inside that parameter down in my main, I get a fault segmentation. I don't know how to declare that string value where I won't get warnings or a segmentation fault. I've tried changing the variable to be a char *first, I tried to do the address. I don't understand it. I would like to know how I can do it so I don't get a warning and it returns an integer smoothly.

```
int baseToDec(int base, char* value)
{
    int len = strlen(value);
    int power = 1, result = 0,i, j, num;

    if(base > 2) //not binary
    {
    for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
            result += number(value[i]) * power;
            power = power * base;
    }
    }
    else if(base = 2)
    {
    while(value[i] == '0' || value[i] == '1' )// (2) remove the most significant binary digit(leftmost) and add it to the result.
    {
            if(value[i] == '1')
            {
                    result = result * 2 + 1;
            }
    else if(value[i] == '0')
    {
            result *= 2;
    }
    i++;
    }       // (3) If all binary digits have been removed, you're done. Stop.
    }
    return result;
}
int main()
{       
    int base, i = 0, j =0, dec; // dec is declared here. 
    char input[100], first[100], second[100];
    char option;
    instructions(); 
    scanf("%s", &option);
    while(option != 'q')
    { 
    i = 0;
    printf("Base: ");
    scanf("%d", &base);
    printf("Input: ");
    scanf("%s", input);      
    while(input[i] != '+' && input[i] != '-' && input[i] != '*' && input[i] != '/')
    {       
            i++;
    }
    printf("%d", i);
    if(input[i] == '+')
    {       
            for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {       
                    first[j] = input[j];
            }
            first[i] = 0;              
            dec = baseToDec(base, first); // Error takes place here. 
    }
}
```

I know it's a lot of writing, but I listed where the errors take place and the method I pass.

Comment: The first step to solving your problem is to isolate the problem. That usually means creating a separate project with only relevant code to reproduce the problem. If you still have issues then you ask a question posting the minimal relevant code.

Comment: @Nina I'll try to reduce the code then

Comment: @Nina However, it might make it difficult for others when viewing it to trace back to certain variables.

Comment: Your `while` loop doesn't stop if it gets to the end of `input` without seeing one of the operation characters.

Comment: @Barmar it does stop, because it stops if the user inputs '+' or those math symbols.

Comment: But it doesn't stop if they DON'T input one of the math symbols.

Comment: @Barmar the error takes place with the string first and the function.

Comment: @Barmar alright, well lets assume that the user does. The error is on my string and char* in my function.

Comment: `if (base = 2)` is assigning the variable, you need to use `==` for testing.

Comment: Why do you treat `base == 2` specially? The conversion process is the same for all bases.

Comment: @Barmar it's a conversion for binary. Regardless, my error is taking place with the string first and char* which is causing me to get a segmentation fault.

Comment: You aren't using any pointers, so the problem is most likely that you're accessing outside the array bounds.

Comment: Have you tried just checking the value of `first` in the debugger?

Comment: @Barmar yes I do. I have a char* value pointer in my parameters for baseToDec function. And on my dec = baseToDec line which is like the last one, I am getting the error, because I am passing a string 'first'. I don't know how to resolve that. That is my issue... unless that is perfectly fine.

Comment: You're not doing any dynamic memory allocation, that's just the way to pass an array to a function.

Comment: @Barmar how can I resolve that, because I don't understand what it means..

Comment: That line is perfectly fine. Arrays decay to pointers when passed as function parameters, it's correct to pass a char array to a `char*` function parameter.

Comment: In `main()`  a `}` seems to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
scanf("%s", &option);
```

When you use `%s`, you have to provide a pointer to a string that can hold the entire input. `option` is a `char`, not a string. It only has room for a single character, but `%s` writes the input word followed by a null terminator.

Use `%c` format to read a single character.

```
scanf(" %c", &option);
```

Also,

```
if (base = 2)
```

should be

```
if (base == 2)
```

But there's no need to treat binary differently from any other base, the conversion process is the same.

Comment: I saw that, however that didn't solve my problem that I have...

Comment: I made this change, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Does `printf("%s\n", first);` show what you expect?

Comment: Yes, I have that on my original code, and it has what it is suppose to

Comment: You never assign any value to `base`.

Comment: I did in my original code, let me put it back up. Someone in my comments told me to reduce it, which I responded with it might not be useful if someone is trying to trace back. I said that, but I'll re edit it so you can see. I did assign and it's in my original code.

Comment: I just added `base = 10`, fixed the `option` scanf, and it works for me.

Comment: Try base 2 for my tests

Comment: Works for me with any base. I added `printf("%s = %d\n", first, dec);` at the end.

Comment: would it work without the if(base == 2) statement? that's why I have that binary one in there, however, I tried that, but I still get the segmentation error

Comment: I don't know why you're getting a segmentation error, I can't see anything that accesses outside the array.

Comment: I changed the first `if` to `if (base > 1)` and it worked fine for base 2.

Comment: I'll try it out